# How to animate a image up and down smoothly. iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uianimation

I want to animate a image up and down smoothly. Any one has idea how to do it..

Answer (score 2):

take a look at a easy UIView (UIImageView) animation [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial)

> One of the coolest things about iPhone apps is how animated many of them are. You can have views fly across the screen, fade in or fade, out, rotate around, and much more!
>   Not only does this look cool, but animations are good indicators that something is going on that a user should pay attention to, such as more info becoming available.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you import following frameworks:

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
`#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>`

```
UIImageView *someImage = .....
CALayer *b = someImage.layer;
// Create a keyframe animation to follow a path to the projected point
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"scale"];
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

// Create the path for the bounces
CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

// Start the path at my current location
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, someImage.center.x, someImage.center.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL,20, 500.0);

animation.path = thePath;

animation.speed = 0.011;
animation.repeatCount = 1000000;

// Add the animation to the layer
[someImage addAnimation:animation forKey:@"move"];
```

You can play around with the values until you get your desired results. Accept this as the answer, if it's your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) showProgressView
{
if (progressViewBack.frame.origin.y == 460.0)
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:progressViewBack];
    [progressViewBack setFrame:CGRectMake(6.0, 460, 308.0, 126.0)];
    [progressViewBack setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 308, 126.0)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [progressViewBack setFrame:CGRectMake(6.0, 334.0, 308.0, 126.0)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
else if (progressViewBack.frame.origin.y == 334.0)
{   
    [progressViewBack setFrame:CGRectMake(6.0, 334.0, 308.0, 126.0)];       
    [progressViewBack setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 308.0, 126.0)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [progressViewBack setFrame:CGRectMake(6.0, 460.0, 308.0, 126.0)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}